# ValueExpression in java throwing null while resolving String and special characters

Tags: java, el

I want to use Java EL to resolve expression.The expression can be any like String,Integer,Float etc.
Following is the map I am setting to context for ElResolver

> ```
> Map<String,String>  varibalesMap= new HashMap<String,String>();
> varibalesMap.put("var1","1000");
> varibalesMap.put("var2","DemoTest");
> varibalesMap.put("var3","3000$ 10 %");
>
> if(null!=dynamicVaribalesMap && !dynamicVaribalesMap.isEmpty())
> {
>   ELContext elContext = JRFContext.getELContext();
>   ELResolver elResolver = elContext.getELResolver();
>   elResolver.setValue(elContext, null, "varibalesMap", varibalesMap);
> }
> String result1=getValuesMap(varibalesMap.get("var1");
> String result2=getValuesMap(varibalesMap.get("var2");
> String result3=getValuesMap(varibalesMap.get("var3");
> ```

I want to iterate through each element of the map and get value for corresponding key from hashmap

```
public String getValuesMap(String result)
{
    ExpressionFactory  expressionFactory = ElContext.getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = ElContext.getELContext();
    ELResolver elResolver = elContext.getELResolver();
    Map<String,String> dynVar=null;
    String returnValue="";
    if(elContext!=null && elContext.isPropertyResolved())
    {
        dynamicVariables=(Map<String, String>) elResolver.getValue(elContext, null, "varibalesMap");
        if(null!=dynVar&& !dynVar.isEmpty())
        {

            ValueExpression variableExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(ElContext.getELContext(), "#{" + dynVar.get(result) + "}", String.class);
            returnValue = (String) variableExpression.getValue(ElContext.getELContext());
        }
    }
        return returnValue;
}
```

Though I am able to see the object populating in

> variableExpression

variable.

> (String) variableExpression.getValue(ElContext.getELContext());  is
>   returning null for String.

```
**Only Integer is working fine.Any inputs would be appreciated.**
```